# what's the proper way to write a .NET application that automatically logs in to www.yahoo.com?

Tags: .net, httprequest

The following code doesn't log in to yahoo. How should it be re-written?

(of course, "username" and "password" would be replaced with my actual account name & password.)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = string.Format("username={0}&passwd={1}", "<username>", "<password>");

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(input);
        writer.Close();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        string x = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: I tried encoding. It didn't work. There are no non-ANSI characters anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When having a look at the html source of the yahoo page, you'll notice there are many hidden fields

[image: image showing the hidden fields of the form]

which are used to protect the user, for example against [CSRF](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery)

It may be, you will habe to firstly send a request to yahoo to get a valid anti CSRF token to then include it into your request. You'll also have to have a look into the javascript the site uses. Maybe there is something calculated on client site, and then send with the login data.

Be aware since those sites often change and maybe tomorrow you're implementation won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a hard time logging in like this and I think it is not really possible. 
If you really need to login programmatically, you would need OpenID or OAuth.

Read more about [Yahoo authentication here](http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several hidden input elements on the form.  It's quite possible there are checks for their existence server-side, possibly along with cookies to verify the request is originating from that log in page.  Have you tried adding them to the request via HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task awhile ago - I had to login to a website and pull out some data out of it. There were no webservices to help me out. I was using VB6 and what I ended up doing is creating a webbrowser object, loading the webpage and logging in like that, then screen-scraped the data I needed.

This approach is crude and unreliable and it won't work if login procedures include captcha protection, but its fast and may help you while you try to figure out a more elegant and permanent approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have an html page that logs into the yahoo mail with some code from their login page. It has worked for a while, so i suggest looking at the html on their login page near the "[Login]" button and figure out which values need to be included with the http request.

Looking at the html page i wrote for login to yahoo mail, you only need to pass the proper HIDDEN values to the server, plus obviously your user and pass. Therefore I recommend you examine the HIDDEN value tags within the html form and experiment to see which ones need to be sent with the http web request. Basically recreating their login page form in .Net Framework style

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that explains OAuth with workflows and code. Besides Yahoo, Twitter is a good site to learn from. Some of the code in the link uses Twitter. Note that OAuth 2.0 is out.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131978/Demystifying-OAuth